# Is there an explicit solution to the reaction diffusion system in the following special form?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

Suppose $\Omega \subset R^N$ is a smooth bounded domain.  Is there an explicit solution to the reaction diffusion equations (RDE) in the following special form?
\begin{equation}    
        \left\{\begin{aligned}
            &\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = a_1\Delta u + u(w-1)& \quad \text{in}~ \Omega\times (0, T]\\ 
            &\frac{\partial w}{\partial t} =  a_2\Delta w + w(u-1) & \\
            &(u,w) = (0,0)& \quad \text{on}~ \partial \Omega\times [0,T]\\
            &(u,w) = (f,g)&\quad  \text{on}~  \partial\Omega\times \{t=0\}
        \end{aligned}\right.
    \end{equation}
where $f$ and $g$ are smooth functions.

The dimension can be N = 1,3 or any dimension, and initial value conditions can be changed if you feel inappropriate, provided that the equation system is in this form. I just wonder if such a system of equations can be solved with an explicit solution.

Expect someone to provide some ideas